# Explicit value of $\overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})}(1).\overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})}(1) $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let us consider the Fubini-Study metric on the part at infinity of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})}(1)$ to obtain the Hermitian line bundle $\overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})}(1)$.

Now we can consider the arithmetic self intersection number $\overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})}(1).\overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})}(1) $, and in [this article](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250518700) it is implicitly stated the value 
$$ \overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})} (1). \overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})} (1)= -\frac{1}{2}.$$

On the other hand, if I try to explicitly compute it I get, choosing for example the sections associated to the homogeneus polynomials $X_0$ and $X_1$:
$$ \overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})}(1) . \overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})} (1) = 0 - \int_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})} \log(\|X_0\|_{FS})\,c_1(\overline{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})}(1))=1.$$

The computation should be quite a standard example, but I didn't manage to find any other indication on the web. What is the correct value?

Thanks!